# debian linux upgrade mysql - continue after looking up differences

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, upgrade

I had to upgrade a mysql server under debian linux because of a database change (with default timestamps, which are not supported by the old version).

Having downloaded the repository package from mysql.com and installed it via

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

i started

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

which got to the point of letting me view differences in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
I decided to take a look and found myself in some command line editor, confirming the differences to be added by the new version would be marginal and could easily be added by hand later. OK so far.

Quitting this editor seamed rather complicated. I played around with the keyboard until i hit Ctrl-Z.

Thereafter i found myself back on the command line and the install script obviously canceled.

When i try to repeat the installation, i get the message

```
E: Konnte Sperre /var/lib/dpkg/lock nicht bekommen - open (11: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
E: Sperren des Administrationsverzeichnisses (/var/lib/dpkg/) nicht möglich, wird es von einem anderen Prozess verwendet?
```

What am i expected to do after quitting this view-diff-editor?
Obviously not to restart the installation from the beginning.
But what then? There is no message on the console hinting to anywhere, and a search by the tokens in the title of this question yields no useful results.

P.S.: The last line after quitting the view-diff-editor possibly was:

```
[1]+  Angehalten              apt-get install mysql-server GUI "tinyca".
```

Not sure about that, but this line doesn't belong to my.cnf and comes below the line...

```
*** my.cnf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [Vorgabe=N] ? D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dselect => 4. Kon[f]ig.   Alle unkonfigurierten Pakete konfigurieren.
```

Und nachdem das Ding endlich wieder läuft:

```
dpkg --pending --configure
```

...wäre auch gegangen (dasselbe in grün).
Und ich wette, dass es unter dem apt-Zeug auch noch ein Fortsetzungs-Dingens gibt...